# Access changes from the beginning of the transaction in after_commit hook

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, transactions

Is there a way to get changes applied on an ActiveRecord from the beginning until the end of the transaction? I tried previous_changes, but it just returns changes applied on the last operation on the ActiveRecord. For example:

```
Account.transaction do
   account = Account.create(name: 'test')
  account.update(last_name: 'testing')
end
```

I would like to know that 'name' and 'last_name' has changed in the transaction.

Answer (score 0):

You can inspect [ActiveModel::Dirty](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveModel/Dirty.html) and just:

```
Account.transaction do
    account = Account.create(name: 'test')
    account.set_attributes(last_name: 'testing')
    account.previous_changes[:last_name].present?
    account.save!
end
```

Comment: It just returns last changes on account. In my example, it would only tell me 'last_name' changed

Comment: previous_changes is used in an after_commit hook, so your example unfortunately doesn't work in my case